# making a responsive long and thin carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Hello and thanks in advance for reading, actually am having a strong issue with a long and thin carousel that is making me nuts :/. The thing is at this site http://gabouh.com/sitio/ the carousel with grey/white color when is resize the window apparently my css it reduces de carousel and looks fine, but if i go directly from an iphone or using mobiletest.me i can see how the site on the mobile is like in a page all thin and the carousel is going out of site, you can see it more specific in http://mobiletest.me/#d=iPhone_5_portrait&u=http://gabouh.com/sitio/

I only need to fix the issue with the responsive of the carousel, i don't know if i should post all my css but if any one could give me an idea of how to make it responsive. Am using bootstrap and am really stuck on how to fix it so any help would be really appreciated.

P.S.: Am already using css mediaquery but still in the resolution of max-width :767px it and adjusting my width of the ul of the carousel to width:100% and doesn't seem to work. If my approach is not good or you know a better one i don't mind checking other ways :D

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see the code and simply wrap it inside a container and it will work perfect with you.

**code:**

```
<div class="container">
   ...... your carousel code .....
</div>
```

try this and i hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: hey thanks for the comment, i already did that, add a new div to wrap all my carousel code. I also added the container class but still having the same issue, i did check the proper function of the mediaqueries but the ul still goes very long, as the width i got there is 9999px xD. Any ways i have made another copy and try another way, could you or any body confirm is the issue persist here:
http://mobiletest.me/#d=iPhone_5_portrait&u=http://conceptografico.mx/initializr

thanks again